# Applying jQuery to HTML elements loaded in by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin DataTables to spruce up my generic html tables.  I can use

`<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('table.display').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>`

To load the DataTables plugin for all pages on the page after it loaded, but it doesn't retroactively work on any tables added through AJAX (because the page has already been loaded at that point).

How do I make sure that the

```
 $('table.display').DataTable();
```

Is run on the table added to the page as well?

Comment: Is your ajax replacing a table that was there before with new data, or simply loading the table after the page initially loads?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I've tried both and can't get either to work.  Basically I have an empty span on the page with the id "table" and then use innerHTML to place the table into the page (because that's how we are being taught to do ajax).

I've also tried inserting it into a table that's loaded initially using the same method (using the table's id instead).  However, even though the initial table works properly, it loses all of Datatables sorting functionality as soon as I input new data via that method.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I figured was happening. If you change the data in the table manually yourself, you'll have to destroy the old datatable and init a new one. See my answer below, it shows a method to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a `ready()` event listener in jQuery to act when each `<table>` is loaded (rather than when the `document` is loaded).

Just add another block, similar to what you have:

```
$('table.display').ready(function() {
    $(this).DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener for new DOM nodes, and call the `.DataTable()` function if the newly added node matches `table.display`:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'table.display' function(e) {
    $(this).DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `DataTable` function must be called on an existing element, there doesn't seem to be a way for you to have all new `table.display` elements automatically get instantiated with by plugin. Try instantiating the new elements in your AJAX success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/your/url',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function (data) { $('table.display').DataTable(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I often have DataTables that are periodically refreshed using ajax. Here is how I instantiate my DataTables in my Ajax success handlers:

```
success: function (response) {
        var $table = $('#user-table');
        var $body = $('#user-table-body');
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable($table)) { // if already init, destroy it
            $table.dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $body.empty(); // empty body of table
        }
        $body.html(response['users-table']) // set new data to body of table 
        $table.DataTable({   // init datatable
            "order": [
                [2, "desc"]
            ]
        });
},
```